# Getting _blazor/negotiate forbidden error 403 on Linux CloudFoundary

Tags: blazor, x-xsrf-token

While negotiating connection Blazor server app throws forbidden error 403 on Linux CloudFoundary server while posting `https://<url>/_blazor/negotiate?negotiateVersion=1`

> Response [{"logref":"eae1ffae68f342bdb285e0caa3dc6265","message":"Gateway error: Invalid CSRF Token 'null' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-XSRF-TOKEN'.","stackTrace":""}]

Please let me know how can I add `X-XSRF-TOKEN` header.